# How to Preview video with Video-React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd, ant-design-pro

I want to show video preview when user select a video in react . Some friend suggested that use `video-react` library for preview video . Could you please guide me how it would be possible and how i can implement video preview in my project . Currently I am using `ant-design` for video selection

**Vide-React Link :**[Click on Video-React](https://video-react.js.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the tutorials.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Player } from 'video-react';

export default (props) => {
  return (
    <Player
      playsInline
      poster="/assets/poster.png"
      src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4"
    />
  );
};
```

For thumbnails you can use `react-video-thumbnail`.
It generates a thumbnail for a given video url. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-video-thumbnail

Comment: but I also want that user play and pause a video there

Comment: Then its' really easy. Just follow tutorials of `video-react`.

Comment: Could you please suggest me tutorial?

Comment: I installed `video-react` but how i can implement function when user select video

Comment: When user select a video set it's url to `state`. Then use it from there. 
If you are using redux or other state managers there will be other solutions.

Comment: Check this one ;) 
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-setstate-in-react-ea8982168b49

Answer (score 0):

Im use react-player, where option "controls" - Set to true or false to display native player controls

```
<ReactPlayer url={'url/to/video'} className={classes.styleView} playing controls/>
```